# HTTP proxy server - need to handle dynamic client

Tags: http, proxy, forwarding

I have developed serve-client model based on UDP. Client are connected to server on random basis. I mean number of clients alive at a time is not fixed. 
Any new client can communicate any time. It means, there could be 1 live client or 100 clients or any number of clients.

Now in such model, I need to add HTTP requests. Browser could send request to server and then server will forward that to any of client based on some identification.
Is there any method or readymade server(like nginix or lighttpd), which I can use for this requirement.

My big worry is that, destination client are not fixed, they keep changing. Most of server (nginix or lighttd) have static entries for destination address.

Comment: Please explain your question a little better, as this is really vague (what kind of answer do you expect?). Are you developing an HTTP load balancer, where the resources that are requested through HTTP will be delivered from a network of clients behind that load balancer, by UDP?

Comment: No. I am not interseted in load blancing. I just want to forward http request from browser to http server - to http client.

Comment: I have one http server and http clients are running on devices. When these devices gets power up then ther starts taking to http server. Now I want to access any one the device from browser. Any request from browser will go through http server for sepcified client based on some identification. How to achieve this request forwarding from server to client. Please note that, clients are not fixed.

Comment: So one client issues a request to your server, then you want this server to forward this request to one or more other clients? Why do you want to do that with HTTP? That protocol has no notion of a server-initiated connection nor pushing unrequested data from the server, and it requires a reliable transport (which UDP isn't). There are tricks and extensions for this and HTTP 2.0 will make it easier, but perhaps another protocol just is a better solution. It would really help if you could explain your scenario somewhat more.

Answer (score 0):

I visualize your scenario as multiple sensors that connect to the servers when they have something to say, and then they send a request and wait for the answer.

I visualize you also want to somehow administer such modules so that you want to access to them via HTTP.

You could leave the new configuration items on the regular server so that upon any update connection the response would include (in a piggy-backed fashion) the changes to the node.

Or the server could mark somehow your interest in accessing a certain node, and then, when this connects, the server could notify the interested client.  The sensor should pay attention to clients wanting to connect to them during a window time.

Certainly, more information would help us help you.